# Three20 - Custom TTTableViewItemCell doesn't highlight when tapped

Tags: iphone, uitableview, three20, custom-cell

I'm using three20 and have custom tableview item, and tableviewitem cell. Im pushing new controller not via item's URL but

```
- (void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

I also overide this method to highlight my cell when taped.

```
//call this to highlight row
- (BOOL)shouldOpenURL:(NSString*)URL {
    return NO;
}
```

When I use standard three20 table items and cells, the row is pefectly highlighted, but when I use my own cell and item it's not. Whac do I have to do? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have

```
self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

set somewhere inside of your custom cell and it should do the trick.